Solution for not being able to connect to a bridge created with Raspberry Pi
I have a question about creating a bridge on Raspberry Pi.
I'm trying to connect to a bridge I created on Raspberry Pi from my iPhone, but the connection is not working.
The hostapd is active, and it appears in the Wifi settings on the iPhone, but when I enter the password, it is rejected.
Is there any solution to this problem?
I'm using a Raspberry Pi 4 Model B Rev 1.2 and an iPhone 11 with iOS 16.0. I also tried it on Android, but it was also rejected.
bridge-utills and hostapd are used.
Here is the configuration.
/etc/hostapd/hostapd.conf
interface=wlan0
bridge=br0
driver=nl80211

ssid=rasp_bridge
country_code=JP
hw_mode=g
channel=7
auth_algs=1
ieee80211n=1

wpa=2
wpa_key_mgmt=WPA-PSK
wpa_pairwise=CCMP
rsn_pairwise=CCMP
wpa_passphrase=1234567890

/etc/network/interfaces
source /etc/network/interfaces.d

auto br0
Iface br0 inet dhcp
    bridge_ports eth0 wlan0


From the tag's excerpt: "PROGRAMMING QUESTIONS ONLY. Questions about general use should be asked on https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/"
